# Heroku CSS file not updating

Tags: css, facebook, heroku

In regards to a Facebook APP I am currently building, I changed some of the codes in the **base.css** file in Heroku, and when I use the commands:

```
git commit -am
git push heroku
```

The page still looks the same after reloading, getting the message "Everything up-to-date".

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Location of the file is: stylesheets/base.css

I also tried:

```
git push heroku stylesheets
```

but that didn't help

Comment: could you post the output of git status?

Comment: @MaxGherkins I did a `git status` and am seeing `nothing added to commit but untracked files present <use "git add" to track>`

Comment: maybe try those: `git add stylesheets/base.css`, `git commit -m 'stylesheet_or_whatever_message'`, `git push origin master` ...

Comment: @MaxGherkins I also did a `git add base.css`, then status, showed it had changed yet when I `git push heroku` did not change. Should I be using the command `git push heroku stylesheets` or `git push heroku base.css` ?

Comment: it's add, commit, push. If you've done the first two git status should tell you, that you're n commits ahead. 

I think if you cloned a heroku default app, the push syntax should be `git push origin master`

Comment: @MaxGherkins I did all that, still not working. I see the words `stylesheets/base.css` in RED

Comment: @MaxGherkins Something really bizarre is going on and I'll need to research this. In my `index.php` file is an http call to `stylesheets/screen.css` and in that file is `@import url("base.css");` I suspect it being the problem. Instead, I just added another call to another stylesheet in my index.php file and content is ok. Scratching my head as to what the issue is with the `@import url` is.

Comment: I think you might have a conflict in your base.css file. this would result in something like this, breaking the syntax: 
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge.

Comment: @MaxGherkins Looking into it now, thanks for the link and the help, cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem with Django on heroku. After following the standard git add, commit, push loop - the server's CSS was not updating. Everything, including static files, had been pushed to the server.

Restarting the heroku server worked though:

```
heroku restart
```

Give that a go!

Answer (score 5):

For me it was Cloudflare caching my styles.

Comment: For me too. The solution is to either go into `developer mode` or purge the cache. Both can be done through the dashboard in Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently and in my case it was a case sensitivity issue. The page referred to the file as theFile.css but the file was actually thefile.css. On OS X with case insensitive file system it was working, but when put on Heroku is broke. Just in case this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should add each branch to commit:

Example:

```
git add css
```

Then commit and push

Answer (score 0):

your Local CSS file will works fine. But if you use bootstrap or material-ui in your project then make sure you used CDN links in index.html file.

After that it will work fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I wanted to suggest two other options if none of the above answers are helping someone get changes to their CSS reflected on Heroku:

- If you are working in Django and your CSS files are stored in your static folder, depending on your configuration you may need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` on your local machine before git adding (`git add .`), git committing (`git commit -m "collecting static files"`) and git pushing to heroku (`git push heroku main` or `git push heroku master`)
- Be sure if you are pushing to Heroku using git that you are pushing only from your main or master branch; I don't believe Heroku will accept other branch names.